# Empty pre-filled TextBox on MouseDown/MouseUp only FirstTime

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm newbie in word-vba (just to let you know that my question could be really stupid).

I would like to clear a textbox only when I click in the textbox the first time.

I've tried For... Next but I wasn't able to comfigure it correctly

```
Private Sub SWName_Field_MouseUp(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
SWName_Field.Text = ""
End Sub
```

I would like that the code will work exactly the same way it works but when I put some text and for example the user make a mistake or typo error the second click in the textbox shouldn't clear the text inside.

Thank you for the support

Comment: You don't provide enough information. Where is this text box? By default, a text box should work the way you say you want: clicking in it will not delete the text. Why would you have code that deletes text?

Comment: The textbox Is in a userform that i've created. With a button i bring the text within the textbox and i put It in a custom field of the Word document.

Comment: Moreover i filled the textbox with anche example that helps People ti uderstand what should be written insider the field

Comment: The help content might be better placed in a static label than in the text box. Then people can refer to it while typing...

Comment: Hi @CindyMeister you're right and I have a static label. But it is non as descriptive as the End Users expect. So basically to make the Form more user friendly I use Label + Field and in the fields I write a sentence and example to help the EU to fulfill it correctly. I know that in this way I just increase code complexity with no added value but that code will be distribute to different people with different mindset. That's all... But at the end of the day I agree with you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no inbuilt activity state identifier in any UserForm control. So you need to use meta data to specify and identify whether or not your mousedown is happening for the first time.

Use `Tag` property of the control for that.

See the code comments for details.

```
Private Sub TextBox1_MouseUp(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)

    '/ Use the Tag field to determine and store the state of Text Box.
    If Len(Me.TextBox1.Tag) < 1 Then
        '/ If Mousedown for the very first  time then TextBox's tag is empty.
        '/ Go ahead, clean the textbox.
        '/ And set a text in tag.
        Me.TextBox1.Text = ""
        Me.TextBox1.Tag = "Text Cleared"
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `Static` local variable to "remember" whether the handler was executed at least once or not:

```
Private Sub SWName_Field_MouseUp(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
    Static executed As Boolean
    If Not executed Then
        SWName_Field.Text = ""
        executed = True
    End If
End Sub
```

The state of the `Static` local is tied to your `UserForm` instance - the value will be "remembered" for as long as the form instance is alive.

This means, if you're showing the form's *default instance*, the state won't necessarily be reset. You will want to ensure you get a fresh default form state every time the form is shown, not just the first time - to do this you `New` up the form:

```
With New UserForm1
    .Show
End With
```

If you just do `UserForm1.Show`, then you don't control when the form instance gets created - VBA does.

You'll also want to control when the form instance gets destroyed - you can do that by handling the form's `QueryClose` event:

```
Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
    If CloseMode = VbQueryClose.vbFormControlMenu Then
        Cancel = True ' cancel the destruction of the object
        Me.Hide ' hide the instance instead
    End If
End Sub
```

With that, the object will be destroyed when execution reaches `End With`. Without it, the object will be destroyed if the user clicks the "X" button, and you probably don't want that to happen (especially if you need to access the form's state after it's closed).

Comment: Hi Mathieu as I stated at the very beginning I'm not an expert at all... But this code is in a dotm (macro enabled template) so each time that I create a new document based on this template the macro start and I can fulfill the fields. So I didn't quite catch if I really need the 2nd and 3rd part of your code. The 1st it seems quite similar to the tag approach. Isn't it?

Comment: Kind of... except it doesn't burry state in a control's property, rather clearly surfaces that state in a local variable. As for the *default instance* stuff, I understand it can be tricky if you have no understanding of classes and objects - just know that whenever you refer to a form by its module name (e.g. `UserForm1.Show`), you're working with one very specific instance of that form (the "default" one), and doing that tends to cause bugs that are pretty hard to diagnose down the line. `Set ui = New UserForm1` and then work with that `ui` object variable instead - cheers!

Comment: Good Morning Mathieu I understand your point. I will try to improve My code... Could you suggest me a book about Word Macro VBA and or specific online course? I've developed this Macro that now works but I see that is not optimized a lot code and it is not flexible if I want to move from a template to another... So I'd like to learn more about this topic. My bests and Thank you